# How to prevent side menu unfolding when swipe on carousel ionic

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm newbie with ionic yet so I wonder to know how to prevent opening left side menu when user swipe on carousel.
Here is the gif that explains what happening [GIF](http://gyazo.com/d948a39573ce891e0f0d567187389d92)

I am swiping owlCarousel to the left it shows next slide - it is ok. When I am swiping to right sidebar begins to unfold. How avoid this?

I asked the same on ionic forum but yet no one helped me.

Comment: Thanks for providing a GIF. Could you also add the relevant part of your code?

Comment: @QueryLars yes, here the [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpmKyz) on fast pen with this problem. While I was doing it I noticed that before I added owlCarousel css file. There was not bug. So I suppose the problem may be with style rules.

Comment: @QueryLars also I start thinking about using [ionSlideBox] (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/) What do you think?

Comment: I would try to get it working with `ion-slide-box`. Compatability shouldn't be an issue then.

Comment: @QueryLars slide-box, didn't helped me (

Comment: For me `ion-slide-box` is working pretty good. Have a look at my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOWEBa) Does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the canDragContent functionality when you are on your carousel view like this:

```
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false)
```

If you still need the canDragContent function in your view you could also encapsulate  that into your carousel callback. So that you only disable the swipeBack funtionality during the carousel is touched.

Comment: My issue is not associated with swipeBack function.